# How was Voldemort supposed to regenerate from a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

To clarify I am not asking [How do Horcruxes work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40118/how-do-horcruxes-work) To me the a horcrux seems to be the same as a phylactery which a lich would use (which I first read about in The Chronicles of Prydain) it is simply a way to keep a soul tethered to this realm but with a stronger link than say a ghost. (There is a chance that eventually Voldemort would have made himself into a being that could not be killed without destroying his horcruxes but that is merely conjecture.) Lilly Potter’s unknown mother’s love protection spell seems to have killed (by reversal or backlash) and split his soul into an uncontained soul shard and into Harry which means it was split into two non-official Horcruxes. This allowed Voldemort as a soul creature thing to regain strength by attaching to Quirrel and drinking Unicorn blood and so forth.

There is evidence that the horcruxes were designed to do more than just contain parts of his soul though. With the Riddle Diary it seemed to be recreating Voldemort as he was at seventeen by taking Ginny's life force. This means that his first horcrux was able to rebuild himself. I find it hard to believe that he wouldn’t make this a feature in all of his horcruxes. (It is my personal opinion that he intended to make a completion spell after creating his seventh official Horcrux and that would have made him close to immortal, something like a lich but without the rotting away.)

Voldemort meant to make 7 Horcruxes. Each one is a splitting of his soul that can tether him to the living world in case his current body is destroyed. Each one also seems to have a some aspect of personality either originally there or put into place by Voldemort. Now Voldemort is too smart to not have a way for each horcrux he made to have a way to recreate him or aid in his regeneration. Assuming that Voldemort wouldn't just make basically what amounts to save points without a way to regenerate. How exactly was he supposed to regenerate and was it different for each Horcrux?

I don’t believe there is a cannon answer so anything directly from the creator or statements made with facts to back them up will be considered. Pure opinion will not.

Also while researching question and answers for this question I've come across conflicting answers for what a horcrux does. So please if you feel there is a duplicate of any kind share a link and specify.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about commenting that it's a possible duplicate is that I always feel it's the duty of the person suggesting it to define why it's a possible duplicate. I have to assume you mean the last part of KHW's answer which doesn't state a source (and sounds more like opinion) or maybe part of DVK's answer which I feel is similar. Either way I can define this question better if it's needed but in it's current state I don't feel it's a duplicate.

Comment: see KHW's answer. It explains that Horcuxes do NOT create a new body, they simply prevent the soul from moving on.

Comment: @KevinHowell I see your (fair) point about KHW's answer not being cited; and yes, I do mean KHW's answer answers your question here.

Comment: Also worth looking at this one: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58573/21267

Comment: @KevinHowell - as an FYI, the duplicate comment is usually generated by SE system itself when someone VTCs as duplicate

Comment: @DVK I realize that. The problem as I was stating it is that someone starts a VTC. I feel it should then be up to that person address why it's a duplicate since the system doesn't. Also I feel I addressed my problem with this answer before this question was closed. It is amazingly frustrating to say the least to post my first question in a year and in less than a day have it closed because a previous answer slightly covered it with out stating source information for that one statement when they had sources for the majority of the rest of the answer.

Comment: @KevinHowell - if you feel that the other answer doesn't really address your need, please post on Meta. If there's consensus that it does not, I will gladly reopen.

Comment: @KevinHowell - you can also comment on the answer lacking sources and ask for them. Or post a bounty. Or at least explicitly explain in your question what you explained in comments.