# Wouldn't one of the horcruxes need to be used up in Voldemort's resurrection?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

I wonder if the number of horcruxes is correct - Harry destroyed the diary, ring, cup, Nagini, locket, diadem and one in himself leaving Voldemort with one piece. Shouldn't one be used in book 4? Voldemort was killed in Godric’s Hollow, or just his soul fled and found Quirrell in Albania 11 years later? Was the same part used in book 4?

Comment: See [K-H-W's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40119/21267)

Answer (score 24):

I think you’re misunderstanding how a horcrux works.

A horcrux anchors your soul to the mortal world, it isn’t a “replacement” soul. You don’t “use it up” when you replace your body.

Suppose you have a single intact horcrux, and your body is killed. The horcrux tethers your soul to the mortal world, and stops the portion of soul in your body from going in the afterlife. That piece of soul is free floating. There are two pieces of your soul.

When you find another body, you implant one of those pieces of soul in the new body (as Voldemort does in *Goblet of Fire*), but you still have two pieces of your soul. One in your new body, one external as a horcrux. You only lose a horcrux if it’s destroyed, or you try to put all the parts back together.

As Voldemort explains, it was the part of soul from his original body that was hiding in Albania, and which came across Quirrell. It was this same soul fragment which he used for his rebirthing in *Goblet of Fire*, and he did that without ever going near his horcruxes.

Comment: Thanks! It makes much more sense now. I read a lot of fanfiction, and some concepts are explained differently - probably thats why I assumed that piece of soul had to be used:)

Comment: Nice answer! I would have tried to have said the same thing just as well :)